# python for loop is not working as it should

Tags: python

```
class Note:

    note_number = 1

    def __init__(self, title="", memo="", id="", tag=""):

        self.memo = memo
        self.id = id
        self.number= Note.note_number
        Note.note_number += 1

    def __str__(self):

        return self.memo

class NoteBook:


    def __init__(self):
        self.note_book = []

    def add_note(self, *args):
            self.note_book.extend(args)

    def print(self):
        for note in self.note_book:
            print(note)

n1 = Note(memo = "I love chemistry")
n2 = Note("I hate chemistry")
n3 = Note("Inorganic")
notebook1 = NoteBook()
notebook1.add_note(n1, n2, n3)
notebook1.print()
```

I've created 3 note objects and added them into the notebook object which is a list using the add_note() function. If I print the notebook with print(notebook1) it correctly displays 3 items within the list. When I try to use the print() function which is suppose to go through the list and print the **str** of each note I only get the first note which is "I love chemistry" and not the other 2 notes why is this the case?

```
I love chemistry
```

Comment: You missed "memo =" for the other 2 note objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `__str__` returns the `memo`. So you should initialise all your notes with `memo`:

```
n1 = Note(memo="I love chemistry")
n2 = Note(memo="I hate chemistry")
n3 = Note(memo="Inorganic")
```

By using `Note("I hate chemistry")` you initialised only the first parameter of `Note`'s constructor, which is the `title`. Saying that, the minimal change you could do, is in the constructor:

```
def __init__(self, memo="", title="", id="", tag=""):
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want it to print the memos - you should create the notes with memos:

Change:

```
n1 = Note(memo = "I love chemistry")
n2 = Note("I hate chemistry")
n3 = Note("Inorganic")
```

to:

```
n1 = Note(memo = "I love chemistry")
n2 = Note(memo = "I hate chemistry")
n3 = Note(memo = "Inorganic")
```

Answer (score 2):

It prints the three items, but only for the first item you have set `memo` to the proper value.

The constructor is defined as:

```
def __init__(self, title="", memo="", id="", tag="") :
```

so the first argument is `title`, and you don't seem to do anything with `title`.

When you construct the notes:

```
n1 = Note(memo = "I love chemistry")
n2 = Note("I hate chemistry")
n3 = Note("Inorganic")
```

Only for the first, you explicitly states `memo =`.

As a result if you call the program, you get as result:

```
$ python3 notebook.py
I love chemistry


$
```

so two blank lines originating from printing notes with `.note` equal to the empty string.